# PostgreSQL 13 - WAL - last file update date doesn't change

Tags: sql, postgresql, wal

I'm using a recent version of PostgreSQL on Windows and trying to understand the internal mechanisms arround WAL files.

The scenario I want to test is the following.

1. Look at the active wal file on the file system

```
SELECT pg_walfile_name(pg_current_wal_lsn());
```

Returns "000000010000000000000007"

**2. Get is last write time**

```bash
ls 000000010000000000000007
```

Returns

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       10/12/2020     13:05       16777216 000000010000000000000007
```

**3. Insert a record into a table of the database**

```
INSERT INTO person(name)
VALUES('Christopher')
```

**4. Check again the last write time of the active wal**

```bash
ls
```

Returns

```
    Répertoire : C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\data\pg_wal

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       27/11/2020     07:45                archive_status
-a----       10/12/2020     11:05       16777216 000000010000000000000007
-a----       06/12/2020     21:15       16777216 000000010000000000000008
```

The WAL hasn't been updated ! Why ?

None of the file in pg_wal has been updated !

**UPDATE** 
Thanks to your answers, I've understand. Windows seems to be the cause !

If I check the date of the file using

```bash
ls
```

```
    Répertoire : C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\data\pg_wal

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       27/11/2020     07:45                archive_status
-a----       10/12/2020     11:05       16777216 000000010000000000000007
-a----       06/12/2020     21:15       16777216 000000010000000000000008
```

**BUT** the following gives the right time !

```bash
ls 000000010000000000000007
```

Returns

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       10/12/2020     13:05       16777216 000000010000000000000007
```

How in the world ?

Comment: 'last file in the pg_wal directory'. Last alphabetically or last by time?

Comment: it's last by time

Comment: The file system may be configured not to update the timestamp on every write.  Updating timestamps on every write doubles the amount of writing which needs to be done.

Comment: @jjanes no, the file is correctly updated but the cause is the 'ls' command on windows that returns two differents result depending if you watch an entire folder or a file specifically.

Answer (score 4):

The active WAL segment will get updated. You can get its name with

```
SELECT pg_walfile_name(pg_current_wal_lsn());
```

The other WAL segments are either old or held in reserve for the future.

There is no reason for the directory modification timestamp to change if one of the files in it changes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Graceful to your query I have been able to retrieve the active wal and check it specifically as I've described in my edited answer.